# Form input is not loaded if target and swap are attached to form

Tags: htmx

The form calls the /pto_calendar/new/save endpoint which returns a new row on a table as html.
I want to add this new row by using **hx-target="pto_table_rows" hx-swap="beforeend"**.
But with adding those attributes **userList** is not being filled.

```
<form id="pto_new_form" hx-post="/pto_calendar/new/save" hx-trigger="submit" hx-target="pto_table_rows" hx-swap="beforeend">
            <div>
                <div>Create new PTO</div>
                <label>Name</label>
                <div id="userList" hx-get="/pto_calendar/users" hx-trigger="load" hx-swap="outerHTML"/>
                <label>Start Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="start" placeholder="Start Date" required/>
                <label>End Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="end" placeholder="End Date" required/>
                <div>Footer Section</div>
                
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Why are those attributes interfering with the user load and is this the right why to implement a form using HTMX anyway?

Comment: Can you provide the backend code for both endpoints used here, so we have more clarity on what you;re trying to do. Also, not sure if that's cousing the issue, but `hx-target` requires css selector.

Answer (score 0):

@mariodev that comment really helped, the code had two issues hx-target was not a css selector and I was missing a target on the input tag. See below

```
<form id="pto_new_form" hx-post="/pto_calendar/new/save" hx-trigger="submit" hx-target="#pto_table_rows" hx-swap="beforeend">
        <div>
            <div>Create new PTO</div>
            <label>Name</label>
            <div id="userList" hx-get="/pto_calendar/users" hx-trigger="load" hx-target="closest div" hx-swap="outerHTML"/>
            <label>Start Date</label>
            <input type="text" name="start" placeholder="Start Date" required/>
            <label>End Date</label>
            <input type="text" name="end" placeholder="End Date" required/>
            <div>Footer Section</div>
            
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```